# Pegar retorno de php em Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estou precisando pegar o valor de uma ajax, após um fetchAll do php

estou fazendo uma função para calcular o frete de uma mercadoria baseada em um banco de dados de entregas que eu possuo, já com um valor pré definido.

Como pegar esse retorno do ajax?

**Sendo assim, eu faço uma requisição via ajax**

```
//funcao ajax
$("#txtCepFrete").on('focusout',function () {
    var cep = $("#txtCepFrete").val();
    $.ajax('classes/getCEP.php',   // request url
     {
          data:{cep:cep},
           success: function (data, status, xhr) {// success callback function
                console.log(data);
          }
    });
 });
```

**getCep.php**

```
require_once ("CEP.php");
$CEP = new CEP();

if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
    $cep = $_GET['cep'];
    if( $cep != ''){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {


            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno->nome_bairro)){
                print_r($retorno);
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }


        }else if(empty($cep)){

            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno->nome_bairro)){
                printf($retorno);
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }
        }
        else{

            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno)){
                printf($retorno);
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**funcao php que faz o calulo e o retorno é recebido de volta pelo ajax**

```
 public function buscarCEPDisponivel()
    {
        try{

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bairros_entregues` WHERE cep_atendido = :cep";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":cep",$this->cep,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            $Exc = new ExceptionDatabase();
            $this->arquivo = $this->Caminho[count($this->Caminho)-1];
            $this->arquivoLog = 'log/erros.txt';
            $this->erro =  $ex->getCode();
            $this->mensagem  = $ex->getMessage();

            $Exc->setArquivo($this->arquivo);
            $Exc->setArquivoLog($this->arquivoLog);
            $Exc->setErro($this->erro);
            $Exc->setMensagem($this->mensagem);

            $Exc->erro();
        }
    }
```

**O retorno**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome_bairro] => Al�pio de Melo
            [cep_atendido] => 30820600
            [frete_bairro] => 3.5
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro o sua requisição **ajax** precisa informar o método que o **PHP** espera. neste caso é necessário usar o método **GET**, assim acredito que script ficaria desta forma:

```
//funcao ajax
$("#txtCepFrete").on('focusout',function () {
    var cep = $("#txtCepFrete").val();
    $.get(`classes/getCEP.php?cep=${cep}`, function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    }, 'JSON');
 });
```

Seguindo a documentação do **jQuery** esta função `$.get` pode definer o retorno que espera do **PHP**, um **JSON** normalmnente.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Porem deve usar o a função `json_encode` ao invés do `print_r` no código **getCep.php**:

```
require_once ("CEP.php");
$CEP = new CEP();

if(isset($_GET['cep'])){
    $cep = $_GET['cep'];
    if( $cep != ''){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {


            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno->nome_bairro)){
                print(json_encode($retorno[0]));
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }


        }else if(empty($cep)){

            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno->nome_bairro)){
                printf($retorno);
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }
        }
        else{

            $CEP->setCepAtendiddo($cep);
            $retorno = $CEP->buscarCEPDisponivel();
            if(empty($retorno)){
                printf($retorno);
            }else{
                print_r('Não encontrou');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: opa, boa, valeu vou testar

Comment: Velho, @Kleber Olivera, o retorno dele vem vazio